# find the closest class with this

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How can I get or find the `.bg` when I'm clicking on the `.button`

```
<div class="button"></div>
<div class="title"></div>

<div class="content">
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="bg">
        Content Goes Here
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get it with next, but then I don't know how can I get inside of the `.content` div

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.button').click(function(){
       $(this).next().next() ...
  });
});
```

I've looked for an answer but all of them was with `.closest()`
which I think I need the opposite of that

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.siblings` and `.find()` as shown :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.button').click(function(){
      alert($(this).siblings('div.content').find('div.bg').html());
  });
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gznpt2kx/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.find()` after traversing to content div:

```
$('.button').click(function(){
  console.log($(this).next().next().find('.bg'));
});
```

### Working Demo

Comment: This will also not going to work if position of tags changes.

Comment: why would the position will change. op has already shared the markup.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.button').click(function(){
      console.log($(this).next().next('.content').find('.bg').html()); 
  });
});
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/gznpt2kx/2/)

Comment: Can't work as it will look for div inside the div.button

Answer (score 0):

You can use .nextAll() and .find() for traversing your DOM:

```
$('.button').click(function(){
   alert($(this).nextAll('.content').find('.bg').html());
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ag8jq0ou/)

**Reference**

[.nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/)

[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Answer (score 0):

Actually what I've meant was this:
to find only the first one so the others wouldn't be affected

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.button').click(function(){
      $(this).siblings('.content:first').find('.bg');
  });
});
```